# discord.js Bot didn't see message before restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

sorry for my bad english.

I want to make a role react bot my problem is my bot don't see message send before his restart

I have take this code but he don't see the reaction on the old messages.

What can I do to make for this code see reaction on the old messages.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.message.fetch();
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
        }
    }
    console.log(`${user.username} reacted with "${reaction.emoji.name}".`);
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.partial) {
        try {
            await reaction.message.fetch();
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
        }
    }
    console.log(`${user.username} removed their "${reaction.emoji.name}" reaction.`);
});

client.login('my token');
```

Answer (score 1):

Along with checking if the reaction message is partial, also check the reaction itself.

```js
if (reaction.partial) {
 try {
  await reaction.fetch();
 } catch (error) {
  console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the reaction: ', error);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
That's don't work i need too send a message and react too him when the bot is on for see reaction on old message.

Comment: I'm not quite following, sorry.